# rego_type_error: undefined function

Tags: unit-testing, open-policy-agent, rego

I am new to OPA and rego files. I have created a rego file like this :

```
package sample.access
import data.myaccess

default allow = false
allow = true {
    myaccess.is_user_allowed(input.user)
}
```

And, I have created test rego file like this :

```
package sample.access

test_allow_positive{
    allow with input as {
        "user": "user1"
    } with data.myaccess as {
        {
            {"user": "user1"},
            {"user": "user2"}
        }
            
    }
}
```

When I run this test case, I am getting error like **"rego_type_error: undefined function data.myaccess.is_user_allowed"**. Help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: If the `myaccess` policy defines the `is_user_allowed` function, ensure that it is loaded when OPA starts.

Comment: yes,its been loaded..

Comment: Could you include your other policy file in your example for completeness?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue, probably the below solution might help.

I had a function `make_err`, in the file `myutils.rego` which I was using in `myModule-test.rego` file.

When I ran the command like this:

```
user@ubuntu:~/rules$./opa test myModule-test.rego
```

Got this error:

```
1 error occurred: myModule-test.rego:7: rego_type_error: undefined function data.myutils.make_err
```

When I gave the below command, it worked:

```
user@ubuntu:~/rules$ ./opa test myutils.rego myModule-test.rego
PASS: 11/11
```

It seems we need to load all the modules on which the current test depends.

Comment: Spent 2 days trying everything. Stupid OPA doesn't resolve dependencies you must manually tell it all files involved in the test case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you are trying to do:

Create a rule, `allow`, which returns `true` if `input.user` is from a set of users passed at the call time. To do this, you can use the rule:

```
package sample.access

allow {
    data.allowed[input.user]
}
```

The corresponding unit tests:

```
package sample.access

test_allow {
    allow with input as {
        "user": "user1"
    } with data.allowed as {"user1", "user2"}
}

test_deny {
    not allow with input as {
        "user": "user3"
    } with data.allowed as {"user1", "user2"}
}
```

Note that you do not need to explicitly import parameters which you will pass at runtime.

If your input data is required to be in the form of a list of `{"user": "id"}`, then instead you should use a [set comprehension](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#set-comprehensions).

```
package sample.access

allow {
    is_user_allowed = {user | user = data.allowed[_].user}

    is_user_allowed[input.user]
}
```

Your unit tests would then need to be amended as such:

```
package sample.access

test_allow {
    allow with input as {
        "user": "user1"
    } with data.allowed as {
        {"user": "user1"},
        {"user": "user2"}
    }
}

test_deny {
    not allow with input as {
        "user": "user3"
    } with data.allowed as {
         {"user": "user1"},
         {"user": "user2"}
    }
}
```